# How do I find matching subtree of HTML nodes in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, tree

I would like to basically do this:

Given our DOM looks like this:

```
<div class="foo bar">
  <ul class="a b c">
    <li class="even">
      <span id="span1">Hello</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="span2">World</span>
    </li>
    <li class="even">
      <span id="span3">!!!</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I say if it matches this pattern?

```
<ul class="a c">
  <li class="even">

  </li>
</ul>
```

Or that it matches this pattern:

```
<ul class="b">
  <li>
    <span>Hello</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Something like this:

```
matches(el, <ul class="b"><li><span></span></li></ul>)
```

Some notes:

- there won't be any wildcards like matching dynamic tag names.
- these are just partial trees, and the attributes values are sometimes a subset, like the class names in the above example.

Comment: sounds like a weird requirement, why do you need this? You could parse the subtree to generate the right css selector and then use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to check if it matches

Answer (score 0):

Just could not tell you how to match the span with text inside. Other than that, all other elements can be checked with css selectors in javascript, like this:

```js
if (document.querySelector("ul.a.c > li.even"))
  console.log("Patern 1 found")
  
  if (document.querySelector("ul.b > li > span"))
  console.log("Patern 2 found")
  
  if (document.querySelector("ul.a.c > li.odd"))
  console.log("Patern 3 found")
```

```html
<div class="foo bar">
  <ul class="a b c">
    <li class="even">
      <span id="span1">Hello</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="span2">World</span>
    </li>
    <li class="even">
      <span id="span3">!!!</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```